# Capture only part of the string without the formatting

Tags: regex, capture

I'm trying to capture only the digits between the `<em>` & `</em>` tags, without the `<b>` & `</b>` tags using basic regex. I've tried to think of ways, maybe lookarounds, but I'm just not that skilled...yet. Here's an example of the raw HTML:

```
<em>4<b>4</b>9/<b>5</b>-<b>7</b>0</em>
```

Here is what I'd like the result to be:

```
449570
```

The problem is sometimes these strings have the formatting HTML, and sometimes not. Sometimes there are extra `-` and `/` symbols, sometimes not. I'm using `<em>.*<\/em>` which is about as simple as it gets!

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe a raw regex is not the easiest solution here - what language are you using?

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language? This would help you a lot.

Comment: For such thing I would just replace all `<b>` and `</b>` occurrences in-place with empty string.

Comment: If you're in the browser, just parse the string and then retrieve the text content of the EM element. For instance, in jQuery: `$( string ).text()`

Comment: I use a program which does all the heavy lifting and only need the regex code to weedle out the bits I need. Believe me, i'd love to be proficient in the whole programming bit, but it's beyond my needs! I hope that answers your Q's.

Comment: @Lucho, Unfortunately that affects a lot of other functions I need. I did try it though, so I'm thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @Toby: Simple Question: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Toby: edited my answer to match your additional requirement with weird chars you want to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said before, regex is probably not the easiest solution for this. But, if you really want to use it then you're probably best doing it in two passes:

```
echo "<em>4<b>4</b>9/<b>5</b>-<b>7</b>0</em>" | sed 's|<[^>]\+>||g' | sed 's|[^0-9]||g'
```

The first `sed` operation removes all html tags. The second removes all non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

First: As always, you probably shouldn't be using regex on html. There will always be edge cases it doesn't catch.

This is even more true if you're using a pure regex of some sort, and since you haven't specified anything else, I'll assume that is what you are using. So really, don't use regex.

That said, I would do this as two regexes - capture the string, then sub out any tags you don't want from the captured string (remember to match them using non-greedy matches!)

Answer (score 0):

E.g. if you're in javascript, try this:

```
var str = "<em>4<b>4</b>9<b>5</b><b>7</b>0</em>";
str.replace(/<em>([^e]+)<\/em>/g, function(match, emInner) {
  console.log(emInner.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
});
```

This prints `449570`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : `<em>(?:(?:<b>)?[0-9]*(?:</b>)?)*</em>`

EDIT 2 : `<em>(?:\D*(\d+)\D*)*?</em>` to handle non-digits characters in the mix, infact it looks event simpler than the first :).

Comment: This will match just `<em><b>...</b><em>`

Comment: I forgot a (?:)* now it should work. Explanation on the downvote please?

Comment: It's matching most of them. The reason the others aren't matching is because there are `-` and `/` symbols mixed into the string. Is there an addition to negate these. My apologies, I realise I omitted this from the initial post. p.s. I didn't downvote you. :)

Comment: I updated the OP with more info. Thanks so far KayKay and others.